# manage.py runserver: error: unrecognized arguments: --insecure

Tags: python, manage.py, django-manage.py

while running server `make run` facing this error[image]

I checked for available solution,like- checked debug setting in 'settings.py' file. I tried to kill redis and celery but didn't worked.

Anyone can provide solution to this error?

Comment: There are obviously several details missing to reproduce the problem.